# How to change the properties of controls of a usercontrol at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am a novice to C#.

My application contains Main form and a few usercontrols.
I want the usercontrol named "uc_MainMenu" to be displayed in the panel named "panel2" inside the Main form when I start running the applicaiton.

```
uc_MainMenu obj_uc_MainMenu = new uc_MainMenu();

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.panel2.Controls.Add(obj_uc_MainMenu);
}
```

It works.

uc_MainMenu contains a few buttons: btnHeadmaster,btnTeacher,btnStudent,btnAttendance,btnExam and btnLogin.
Each of those buttons' click will bring the corresponding predefined usercontrols.

Here is my question.
I want to disable all the buttons except btnLogin when the form loads.
How can I do that?

I tried this way but it didn't work.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in panel2.Controls)
 {
     if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
         {
            ((Button)ctrl).Enabled = false;
         }
  }
```

I can change each button's enabled properties in the uc_MainMenu, but if so I will have to change them again whenever I switch the usercontrols. That's why I left their enabled property to true when I designed the usercontrols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property inside user control :

```
public bool MyButtonEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return anyButtonButNo_btLogin.Enabled;
    }
    set
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button) && ((Button)ctrl).Name != "btLogin")
            {
                ((Button)ctrl).Enabled = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this property anywhere that usercontrol used.

```
uc_MainMenu obj_uc_MainMenu = new uc_MainMenu();

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.panel2.Controls.Add(obj_uc_MainMenu);

     ///this property will access the button inside that user control
     obj_uc_MainMenu.MyButtonEnabled=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in obj_uc_MainMenu.Controls)
 {
     if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button) && ((Button)ctrl).Name != "btLogin")
         {
            ((Button)ctrl).Enabled = false;
         }
  }
```

Notice that I changed panel2 by obj_uc_MainMenu.

Comment: this code can be simplified: `foreach (var btn in obj_uc_MainMenu.Controls.OfType<Button>()) btn.Enabled = btn == btLogin;`

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons is inside the obj_uc_MainMenu, then you can not retrieve it via panels.Controls. If you want to retrieve them, you should use obj_uc_MainMenu.Controls.

I don't know how did you define the user control obj_uc_MainMenu, then I guest you can do something like this:

```
     foreach (Control ctrl in obj_uc_MainMenu.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                ((Button)ctrl).Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find will find the panel. If it exists, then iterate through the usercontrol for type button and modify the button/s properties. No need of casting for button within foreach loop (we know its of type Button).

```
// Get the panel
var panel2 = Controls.Find("YourPanel", true).FirstOrDefault() as Panel;

// If it exists
if (panel2 != null)
{
    foreach (var button in panel2.obj_uc_MainMenu.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        // Set the value of each one
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may answer the authors question, you may want to expand your answer with some text and links to documentation. Explain what your code does and how it helps the author to solve his/her problem.

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't use the FindControl. It says the name FindControl does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Try Controls.Find